how to convert 2d array output of predicted classes given by sparse categorical entropy into predicted classes
I was given an assignment at the university to write a classifier of simple text dataset. I have 5 classes: ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4']. I don't understand neural networks well and using internet i wrote something =)
BUT
if i use categorical_crossentropy it gives me an error
Arguments 'target and 'output' must have the same rank (ndim). Received: target. shape=(None,), output.shape=(None,6)

If i use 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy' it gives me 2d array in output.
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_scaled, y_encoded, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

x_train = x_train / 255
x_test = x_test / 255

def b_m(hp):
    model = Sequential()
    activation_choice = hp.Choice('activation', values=['relu', 'sigmoid', 'tanh', 'elu', 'selu'])
    model.add(Dense(units=hp.Int('units_input',
                                   min_value=512,
                                   max_value=1024,
                                   step=32),
                    input_dim=2,
                    activation=activation_choice))
    model.add(Dense(units=hp.Int('units_hidden',
                                   min_value=128,
                                   max_value=600,
                                   step=32),
                    activation=activation_choice))
    model.add(Dense(5, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(
        optimizer=hp.Choice('optimizer', values=['adam','rmsprop','SGD']),
        loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
        #loss='categorical_crossentropy',
        metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

tuner = kt.Hyperband(b_m,
                     objective='val_accuracy',
                     max_epochs=10,
                     factor=3,
                     directory='test_dir')

stop_early = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=5)

tuner.search(x_train, y_train, epochs=50, validation_split=0.2, callbacks=[stop_early])

best_hps=tuner.get_best_hyperparameters(num_trials=1)[0]

model = tuner.hypermodel.build(best_hps)
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=50, validation_split=0.2)

val_acc_per_epoch = history.history['val_accuracy']
best_epoch = val_acc_per_epoch.index(max(val_acc_per_epoch)) + 1

hypermodel = tuner.hypermodel.build(best_hps)

hypermodel.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=best_epoch, validation_split=0.2)

eval_result = hypermodel.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
print("[loss, test]:", eval_result)

y_pred = hypermodel.predict(x_test)


So, i have three questions: 1. what type of loss is best to use in this situation?
2. if it is better to use categorical_crossentropy, then how to fix the error that occurs
3. if it is better to use sparse_categorical_crossentropy, then how to convert the output from a 2d array to a one-dimensional array with classes
please help
I tried to reshape input data and change parameters of my model but nothing happend

Hi ,Your labels are integers (, e. g., 0, 1, 2, etc. ), so ‘sparse_categorical_crossentropy’ is the better option as it compares the integer labels directly to the predicted probability distribution. Note that you can use ‘categorical_crossentropy’ only if the labels are one-hot encoded.Second point your model outputs class probabilities as a 2D array. to convert 2d array to a one-dimensional array use 'np.argmax()'.
